# Aren't players required to choose a subclass?

Tags: log-horizon

Most of the characters (at least up to episode 5, since I haven't gone any further) seem to have *both* class and subclass:

- [Akatsuki](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Akatsuki): **Class** - Assassin; **Subclass** - Tracker
- [Shiroe](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Shiroe): **Class** - Enchanter; **Subclass** - Scribe
- [Nyanta](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Nyanta): **Class** - Swashbuckler; **Subclass** - Chef
- [Serara](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Serara): **Class** - Druid; **Subclass** - Maid

However, [Naotsugu](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Naotsugu) (whose Class is Guardian) appears to not have a Subclass.

From the [Classes](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Classes) and the [Subclasses page](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Subclasses) on Log Horizon Wiki, one can tell that once a player starts playing Elder Tale he *has to choose* a Class, which cannot be changed again. However, one also gathers that Subclasses, on the other hand, are changeable, but the site says nothing about whether or not a player is *required* to have one.

**Does this mean that Subclasses are not required?

Or was Naotsugu's class just not yet revealed/unknown?**

Comment: Naotsugu's subclass is 辺境巡視 (Border Patrol/Frontier Guard).

Comment: Is that revealed later on the Anime? Or on the Novel or Manga?

Comment: It is mentioned in the [web novel](http://ncode.syosetu.com/n7875cd/5/) at least.

Answer (score 2):

The wiki page you referenced for Naotsugu has been updated saying that he has the [Border Patrol](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Border_Patrol) Subclass.

On a side note if Elder Tale is anything like most MMORPGs a subclass is not chosen until you have gained a couple levels and there is no advantage for not having one. So it would make sense that most players would pick a subclass to start leveling it right away.